# Negative resistance circuit stability

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, impedance

Assume we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkWRNI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which will be the current flowing in such a circuit.Can we say that the resistors are in resonance?(similar to a parallel LC circuit when Xl = Xc).

And which is the difference of the above circuit and this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyrfjB.png)</sup>

If circuit 2 is stable then why cant circuit 1 be stable?

Comment: Both are stable because the voltage is fully defined and the branch currents are defined by the individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with either of these circuits. You can even build the first circuit in practice and measure its characteristics; the only difficulty will be building the negative resistor - it'll have to be an active circuit (containing OpAmps and power transistors).

Let's calculate the currents flowing in the first circuit:

1 Volt across the 10 Ohm resistor causes a current of 100mA to flow through it. Similarly, 1 Volt across the -10 Ohm resistor causes -100mA to flow through it. Using KCL, we find that the current flowing out of the voltage source is zero.

The circuit is perfectly stable and well-defined. Things only start to break down when you remove the voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

> *Which will be the current flowing in such a circuit.*

To calculate the impedance of two parallel resistors (irrespective of polarity), we use "product" divided by "sum" and, given that the sum is 0, the impedance presented to the battery/voltage source will be infinite in magnitude. This means that no current will ever flow from the source and, that is also true if the source is AC and, at any frequency.

> *Can we say that the resistors are in resonance?*

No, because there is no change (from zero) in the current produced by the source that is dependent on frequency. The two resistors might as well be removed to get the same effect.

> *which is the difference of the above circuit and this circuit*

The LC circuit does have a resonance and, when the source produces an AC frequency equal to the resonant frequency, the impedance of the L and C (together) will be infinite i.e. the same as the original circuit and, the same as a voltage source with nothing connected to it. At all other frequencies a current flows and, under these circumstances the two circuits are dissimilar. It's the frequency-dependent nature of an LC circuit that defines it as being able to resonate.

> *If circuit 2 is stable then why cant circuit 1 be stable?*

Who says that circuit_1 is unstable?